# How do i enque this script into wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So a friend who as an app out in iTunes, made me a script to use a part of it in a website. He doesnt work with wordpress, and gave it to me to figure out, but cant really get it to work. Whats the best approach here? he gave me a .htm file, and the code inside looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
Skatespots
<div id="spotsContainer">

</div>

<script>

(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '10.0.1') {
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src","https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js");
if (script_tag.readyState) {
  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
      if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
      }
  };
} else {
  script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
}
// Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
  // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
jQuery = window.jQuery;
main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
// Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
// new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
// Call our main function
main(); 
}

function main() { 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    $.getJSON("http://sk8spots.com/Core/GetData?userId=9914bd37-2526-4c0e-95ed-ad16b045ab89&callback=?", function(data) {

var str = "";
$.each(data.Model, function (i, item) {
            str += "<div class='item' style='height:200px;width:250px;float:left;'><img src='http://sk8spots.com/imageBank/" + item.Images[0].Id + ".jpg?width=100&height=100&bgcolor=white' width='100' height='100' /><p>" + item.Name + "</p><p>" + item.Description + "</p></div>";
    });
    $("#spotsContainer").append(str);
console.log(data);  

    });
});
}

})();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue your JavaScript. Create a file called script.js and upload it to a folder inside your theme's directory. For example: /my-theme/js/script.js

Then you would make use of the `wp_enqueue_script` function. So, for example:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Thanks. Cant get it to work though, it loads and shows the page, but its empty. Same result with the example code.

Comment: Where are you putting the example code? It will need to go in your functions.php file inside your theme. See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained